In which area of memory is an instance of 'Array', one of Swift's collection types stored?
As the title said, if I create an instance of type 'Array' as in the code below, which area of memory is it created?
var array: Array<Int> = [0, 1, 2]


When initializing an instance of the Array structure type using a literal value in 'array', the 'init(array literal:)' method is called.
When the initializer is called in the 'Element...' type, the argument label array literal of the 'init (arrayLiteral elements: Element...)' can be received by grouping the transmitted arguments in an array.
For this reason, the values transferred to the variable arguments are stored in the Heap area, not the Stack area, when the function is called.
Is the 'array' variable stored in the stack as an instance of the 'Array' structure itself, and the metadata (Element Type, Count, Capacity, etc.) stored in the heap, as shown below?


I will assume that you have read this post about where things are stored in memory in general.
Array is a struct, a value type. The struct instance (of a fixed size of 8 bytes on my MacBook) could be stored anywhere, depending on where you declared it:

If it is a local variable in a function, it's probably on the stack. It technically can also fit in a register.
If it is a property of a reference type, it would be in the heap, where the enclosing class instance is stored.
If it is a static/global variable, it might just be in the .data section of the executable.

The struct instance isn't where the elements of the array are stored though. The elements are stored in an instance of a reference type (see the class __ContiguousArrayStorageBase), which the struct instance holds a reference to. This class instance is in the heap, and it also contains the capacity and element count of the array, so your diagrams is quite accurate in those aspects.

Regarding init(arrayLiteral:):
The init(arrayLiteral:) initialiser is almost certainly not called when you do var x = [1, 2, 3]. The compiler knows that you are creating an Array here, and not some other type that is expressible by an array literal. That initialiser is just to satisfy the protocol requirement. It would only be called in situations like:
func foo<T: ExpressibleByArrayLiteral>(_ type: T.Type) where T.ArrayLiteralElement == Int {
    let x: T = [1, 2, 3]
}

// this will cause [Int].init(arrayLiteral:) to be called
foo([Int].self)

And this has nothing to do with where array is eventually stored anyway.
